# How to access filename from a folder using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am trying to build a simple website with just an index file and a folder full of icons for our internal purpose. I am making this so that anyone in our team can just access the link and download the icons whenever needed without our help. I am trying to read the icons file name from the folder automatically, so every time we update the folder with new ones we don't have to edit the HTML. I know only JavaScript. Please help me.

Comment: not going to happen with JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: @epascarello I don't know, nodejs & express? :)

Comment: this is a so much duplicate

Comment: @epascarello Is there any simple way to do?

Comment: When you update run a small bat/script to list out the names to a file (something like `ls path > list.txt`), then read/parse that file from js instead. You won't have access from js to list the files directly. This is such a elegant solution I have awarded myself a glass of soda.

Comment: @K3N How would you read that file with client-side JavaScript?

Comment: @freginold assuming it ends up in the same folder as the images or as the index.html, you can read it using fetch() or XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @K3N Sorry, brain fart. You should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be to produce a filelist of the files via a script or batch file (depending on OS, something like - in psudeo - `ls path/to/images > filelist.txt`) which redirect the output to a file that ends up in the same root as the index and images.

This file could then be read via `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()` and parsed on client side to provide the basis for the links to the updates files.

This would require an extra step in the pipe-line of course, but could easily be automated using a listener for the image directory that triggers the script, part of your project setup and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. In your case Javascript is running in the browser (client-side). It has no access to the servers filesystem. You need a server-side dynamic web-service (php, node.js, ...)

Comment: Why wouldn't the solution @K3N proposed in the comments above (save file names to txt file, read it in w/ JS) work?

Comment: Yes. This could be a solution. But then they would have to change the text-file each time they are changing files in their servers filesystem.

Comment: True, but could be done with an automated script/task.

Comment: Yeah. He got an upvote from me for this dirty but effective solution ;-) But I think that it would be easier to extend the existing static html-files with dynamic php-code-snippets for reading the filesystem and providing link generation.